# I'm looking for best algorithms to compare two Circular Linked List?

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, java

I'm looking for best algorithms to compare two Circular Linked List?

For example :

List 1 = 1-3-5

List 2 = 3-5-1

I want to compare "same" or "not same"  but need fast algorithm.

Comment: This is solved in linear time on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2555887/940550.

Comment: Are you sure @YuvalFilmus ? This solution is so long ?

Comment: Fortunately, I don't have to be sure - it's your question, not mine. Now that you know how the problem is called and what algorithms can be relevant, you should be able to figure out the answer yourself.

Comment: What does "same" or "not same" exactly mean? To me, two linked lists are the same if they have the same pointer to the first element, so I just write list1 == list2.

Comment: (The most simple algorithm is to just answer "same".)

Answer (score -1):

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
};


Node* removeLeadingZeros(struct Node* a)
{
    if (a != NULL && a->data == 0)
        return removeLeadingZeros(a->next);
    else
        return a;
}


int getSize(struct Node* a)
{
    int sz = 0;
    while (a != NULL) {
        a = a->next;
        sz++;
    }
    return sz;
}


void push(struct Node** head_ref, int new_data)
{
    
    struct Node* new_node = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    
    new_node->data = new_data;


    new_node->next = (*head_ref);

    
    (*head_ref) = new_node;
}

int compare(struct Node* a,
            struct Node* b)
{


    a = removeLeadingZeros(a);
    b = removeLeadingZeros(b);

    int lenA = getSize(a);
    int lenB = getSize(b);

    if (lenA > lenB) {

    
        return 1;
    }
    else if (lenB > lenA) {
        return -1;
    }

    
    while (a != NULL && b != NULL) {
        if (a->data > b->data)
            return 1;
        else if (a->data < b->data)
            return -1;

        /* If we reach here, then a and b are
        not NULL and their data is same, so
        move to next nodes in both lists */
        a = a->next;
        b = b->next;
    }

    
    return 0;
}

// Driver code
int main()
{

    struct Node* a = NULL;
    push(&a, 7);
    push(&a, 6);
    push(&a, 5);

    struct Node* b = NULL;
    push(&b, 3);
    push(&b, 3);
    push(&b, 2);

    cout << compare(a, b);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you try and present the algorithm underlying the C++ implementation presented as succinct *pseudo code*, it is quite easy to use lines containing just `~~~` around a pre-formatted ("code") block. Alternatively, append two blanks to each line for an effective line break and use `  ` ("digit" blanks) for indentation.

Comment: We're not a coding site and we're not looking for answers that just consist of a block of code.  Instead, we're looking for answers that provide explanation, ideas, concise pseudocode, and/or proofs of correctness.